# Git ignore files locally

Tags: git

I have webroot/wp-config.php file which is modified but for obvieus reasons I don't want to commit it. I don't want to pollute the global git config (.ignore) so I've added the file to

.git/info/exclude

```
# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~
webroot/wp-config.php
```

and I've run

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged webroot/wp-config.php
```

but still when I run git status I see webroot/wp-config.php as modifed in "Changes to be commited".

```
# On branch develop
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 8 commits.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   webroot/wp-config.php
#       modified:   webroot/wp-content/themes/wp-intouch/functions/twitteroauth.php
#
```

PS. I've tried --skip-worktree too, but the same result.

```
git update-index --skip-worktree webroot/wp-config.php
```

PS2. Windows 7 & git 1.7.11.msysgit.1

Comment: When you have `changes to be committed` the changes have already been `git add`-ed, and—just as it says in the `git status` output—you can use `git reset` to "un-stage".  After that your exclude entry will keep the file from getting re-added, unless you override that explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually used `.git/info/exclude` to ignore a file... (But, as it is not a shareable folder, I'd probably never use it at this end risking other colleague commiting files I don't want to see in the repo)

As so, I strongly believe there's nothing wrong adding this config file to the global `.gitignore`.

Though, as you're on SO for an answer and not an opinion. I'd suggest you use a `.gitignore` file inside the folder where `wp-config.php` is located. You can have multiple `.gitignore` files throughout your repository and they can be located in sub folders. It is, for example, in local `.gitignore` that local configs and cache files are ignored in Laravel (e.g. ).